# Objectify - does transaction throw ConcurrentModException in case of simultaneous creation of an entity?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, transactions, objectify

Does Objectify throw a ConcurrentModificationException in case an entity with the same key (without a parent) is created at the same time (when before it did not exist) in two different transactions? I just found information regarding the case that the entity already exists and is modified, but not in case it does not yet exist...

```
            ofy().transactNew(20, new VoidWork() {

            @Override
            public void vrun() {
                Key<GameRequest> key = Key.create(GameRequest.class, numberOfPlayers + "_" + rules);
                Ref<GameRequest> ref = ofy().load().key(key);

                GameRequest gr = ref.get();
                if(gr == null) {

                    // create new gamerequest and add... 
                    // <-- HERE
                } else {
                    ...
                }


            }
        });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will get CME if anything in that entity group changes - including entity creation and deletion.

The code you show should work fine. Unless you really know what you are doing, you're probably better off just using the transact() method without trying to limit retries or forcing a new transaction.  99% of the time, transact() just does the right thing.

Comment: Even though we do not specify a parent/entity group and therefore cannot be sure "where" in the datastore that entity is created?

Comment: If you do not specify a parent (or have a null parent), then your entity *is* the root of the entity group. There is no ambiguity.